# Play a video only from my app

Tags: java, android, vimeo-android

I'm trying to play some private videos from my Vimeo account.
I don't want anyone to be able to downlod or access outside my app.
I don't care if I have to use a seperate server and do some PHP, but I want to be able to verify that the request to get the video came from my app and not someone random trying to see my video.

I'm open to the idea of moving my videos to somewhere else (not download with my app).

A way to verify that the person trying to access my video to watch is using my app.

Comment: Maybe create a dropbox folder (and move your videos there) shared with a single user account. Your app is that user. All the installed app instances will use the same account.

Comment: Well, you can easily decompile the app and get the password whatever you do it you can get the account's password

Comment: **1** - Not everybody has the knowledge to do that. **2** - you can try to hide your login data better.

Comment: My client charges usually $600 for these videos to be accessed, and using a username and a password aren't enough because they can get the url if they are really interested and pay 600$ once and re-sell his videos, so no matter how good I hide his data if someone really wants to he'll get it

Comment: So, what do you plan to do?

Comment: I'm not sure yet, still trying to find a solution, if I find a good one I'll post it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try and use JWT (Json Web Token) to verify who is sending the request, you can use firebase and send the logged in user's token and use it's api to verify that the token is valid